# get 419 error when posting from axios to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have the csrf which it's already attached to the axios header at bootstap.js,
I get always this response from server when try to post simple post (they are three pictures below explaining my situation)

**axios post from vue file**:
[image: axios post from vue file]

**Route at web.php**:
[image: Route at web.php]

**result 1**:
[image: result 1]

**result 2**:
[image: result 2]

Comment: Hello, please provide the actual code instead of screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Did u add `csrf_field` correctly? Also, list yours headers

Comment: I can't replicate this given what you have posted.

Comment: @GONG Yes i did it correctly

Comment: Can you also show how you handle the error? The default response isn't json I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me so far but you'll be without CSRF, go to 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken' then edit the protected variable to this

```
 protected $except = [
     "/*"
 ];
```

the `'/*'` says to exclude CSRF from all routes, although this isn't ideal it should fix the problem, Maybe just exclude those specific routes that are throwing you the error?

e.g. `"/specificRoute"`